# how to I add characters to rows that do not have them

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

The first few line of my data looks like

```
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    gene    3591    3908    0.61    -   .   g1
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    transcript  3591    3908    0.61    -   .   g1.t1
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  3591    3593    .   -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    CDS 3591    3908    0.61    -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    exon    3591    3908    .   -   .   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    start_codon 3906    3908    .   -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
```

I need to add `";` to the rows in the last columns that lack them. I already used `grep -v transcript_id canada.gtf | grep -v "^#"` to identify those rows that lack them. Can I use a linux command to do this?

Comment: `grep -v "^#"` does not reflect your condition. Post the expected output

Comment: I need to have something like  this

Comment: scaffold10x_1 AUGUSTUS gene 3591 3908 0.61 - . g1";
scaffold10x_1 AUGUSTUS transcript 3591 3908 0.61 - . g1.t1";
scaffold10x_1 AUGUSTUS stop_codon 3591 3593 . - 0 transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1 AUGUSTUS CDS 3591 3908 0.61 - 0 transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1 AUGUSTUS exon 3591 3908 . - . transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1 AUGUSTUS start_codon 3906 3908 . - 0 transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1 AUGUSTUS gene 4003 4530 0.4 - . g2";
scaffold10x_1 AUGUSTUS transcript 4003 4530 0.4 - . g2.t1";

Comment: @OlukayodeNewEdgeDaramola Don't post unformatted data like that in the comments. Update your question to include the desired output.

Comment: sorry, I a new here, just trying to understand the platform.

Comment: Don't you need to add a `"` before `g1` and `g1.t1` too?

Answer (score 1):

**`sed`** approach:

```
sed 's/[^[:space:]]\+[^;[:space:]]$/"&";/' file
```

The output:

```
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    gene    3591    3908    0.61    -   .   "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    transcript  3591    3908    0.61    -   .   "g1.t1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  3591    3593    .   -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    CDS 3591    3908    0.61    -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    exon    3591    3908    .   -   .   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    start_codon 3906    3908    .   -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
```

Comment: `\+` doesn't do what you want in standard BRE (it does in GNU sed, but that's just GNU sed)

Comment: thanks, that works. but was wondering if i could make the columns having "g1" and "g1.t1" have transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1"; instead. The same apply to the rest.

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` command will make sure that each line ends in exactly one semicolon and that the last word in each line is quoted:

```bsh
sed -e 's/"\?\([a-z0-9.]\+\)"\?;*$/"\1";/' canada.gtf
```

Here is the output from this command:

```
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    gene    3591    3908    0.61    -   .   "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    transcript  3591    3908    0.61    -   .   "g1.t1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  3591    3593    .   -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    CDS 3591    3908    0.61    -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    exon    3591    3908    .   -   .   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    start_codon 3906    3908    .   -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
```

If you want to modify the file in-place then you can use the `-i` flag:

```bsh
sed -i -e 's/"\?\([a-z0-9.]\+\)"\?;*$/"\1";/' canada.gtf
```

If you just want to make sure that each line ends with `";` (and you don't want a match `"` at the beginning of the last word in the line) then you could use the following command instead:

```bsh
sed -e 's/"\?;\?$/";/' canada.gtf
```

And here is the output from this command:

```
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    gene    3591    3908    0.61    -   .   g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    transcript  3591    3908    0.61    -   .   g1.t1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  3591    3593    .   -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    CDS 3591    3908    0.61    -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    exon    3591    3908    .   -   .   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    start_codon 3906    3908    .   -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
```

Comment: I think this just needs the double quote character as well. But it may need to surround the last field, if I’m interpreting it correctly.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yeah, I think I probably misread the question. Thank you for the comment - updated.

Answer (score 0):

@Kay NewEdge Daramola

By using below oneliner i achived the result

Code:

---

```
sed  's/[a-z][0-9]$/&";/g' example.txt |sed 's/[a-z][0-9].\{2\}/"&/g'
```

---

output

---

```
scaffol"d10x_1   AUGUSTUS    gene    3591    3908    0.61    -   .   "g1";
scaffol"d10x_1   AUGUSTUS    transcript  3591    3908    0.61    -   .   "g1.t1";
scaffol"d10x_1   AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  3591    3593    .   -   0   transcript_id ""g1.t1"; gene_id ""g1";
scaffol"d10x_1   AUGUSTUS    CDS 3591    3908    0.61    -   0   transcript_id ""g1.t1"; gene_id ""g1";
scaffol"d10x_1   AUGUSTUS    exon    3591    3908    .   -   .   transcript_id ""g1.t1"; gene_id ""g1";
scaffol"d10x_1   AUGUSTUS    start_codon 3906    3908    .   -   0   transcript_id ""g1.t1"; gene_id ""g1";
```

---